# Filtering in-memory collection: does IQueryable give better performance?

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, ienumerable, iqueryable

Let's say I have an in-memory collection(Persons) on which i have to apply some filter condition.

```
var distinctproductKeys = persons.Where(d => d.productsDictionary != null)
                                 .SelectMany(d => d.productsDictionary.Keys)
                                 .Distinct();
```

vs. if i use IQueryable before applying filters

```
var distinctproductKeys = persons.AsQueryable()
                                 .Where(d => d.productsDictionary != null)
                                 .SelectMany(d => d.productsDictionary.Keys)
                                 .Distinct();
```

I have read that once you have your collection in-memory, both IQueryable and IEnumerable gives same performance.. But running both the queries i observed IQueryable version is more fast. Can someone tell me why?

Comment: What type is Persons of?

Comment: can you show us, how did you test it and what did you get as a result?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how you are testing your performance but the main thing to remember when working with **IQueryable** and **IEnumerable** are that both will give you **deferred execution**.

The **difference** is that IQueryable is the interface that allows LINQ-to-SQL (LINQ.-to-anything really) to work. So if you further refine your query on an IQueryable, that query will be executed in the database, if possible.

For the IEnumerable case, it will be LINQ-to-object, meaning that all objects matching the original query will have to be loaded into memory from the database.

In code:

```
IQueryable<Customer> custs = ...;
// Later on...
var goldCustomers = custs.Where(c => c.IsGold);
```

That code will execute SQL to only select gold customers. The following code, on the other hand, will execute the original query in the database, then filtering out the non-gold customers in the memory:

```
IEnumerable<Customer> custs = ...;
// Later on...
var goldCustomers = custs.Where(c => c.IsGold);
```

This is quite an important difference, and working on IQueryable can in many cases save you from returning too many rows from the database. Another prime example is doing paging: If you use Take and Skip on IQueryable, you will only get the number of rows requested; doing that on an IEnumerable will cause all of your rows to be loaded in memory.

Comment: IEnumerable gives me immediate execution, for instance IEnumerable<Movie> list = query.Where(p => p.Title.Contains("first")).AsEnumerable();  put query to database before foreach